# SOAP Message Handler

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws, soap-client

I have a WSDL URL that i used to create a  web service client using  wsimpot command
now  i want to  log all  the in-going and the  outgoing XML
so i think to user  SOAP  Handler but it did not works with this  service
but it works with another  service  client  . So my question here is this the right way  to log the  calls as i need to log all the parameters and log the  response also or there is  another way  .

and  why  the handler  did not work  with this client but works with other clients ?

Comment: Questions is not clear. you mean in the client side or in the server side?

Comment: the client  side @Zeus

Comment: what implementation for soap-client you use

Comment: JAX-WS @AlekseiBulgak

Comment: jax-ws is only a specification. It has a lot of implementations like Apache CXF, Jersey and so on

Comment: for example in CXF you simply need to add [LogginfFeature](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/feature/LoggingFeature.html) for logging all request/responses. So I suppose it is depends on implemenatation

Comment: Oracle Weblogic implimntation   @AlekseiBulgak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you implemented your handlers - a normal way to achieve such functionality is just to add a handlerChain, similar to this:

```
bindingProvider.getBinding().setHandlerChain(CollectionUtils.toList(new Handler[]{new SimpleHandler()}));
```

Within the SimpleHandler (that obviously must implement: `SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>`), you'll basically do something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean handleMessage(final SOAPMessageContext messageContext) {
    if (messageContext == null) {
        LOG.warning("The messageContext was nilled. Unable to handle the soapMessage.");
        return false;
    }
    if (Boolean.FALSE.equals(messageContext.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY))) {
        LOG.finest("Some cool incoming message");
    } else {
        LOG.finest("Some cool outgoing message");
    }
    return true;
}
```

The `bindingProvider` mentioned earlier, you'll snap from the initialization of the WebService itself. Most likely something like this:

```
final SomeCoolService someService = new SomeCoolService("my/path/to/service.wsdl", new QName(.., ..));
    coolServicePort = remedyService.getCoolServicePort();
    if (coolServicePort != null) {
        final BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) coolServicePort;
```

In your case, the handler you added didnt work - did it even get initialized during the init of the handler-chain?

The less obvious way to log these things, is by using other tools such as Wireshark, however I doubt that is suffient for you - unless you'll just want to trace whatever being sent back/forth.

Comment: SO  i would like to ask  how can i get the PortInfo  so i can pass  it to  getHandlerChain (PortInfo arg0 ) method  as i had implements the  HandlerResolver and add my  custom SOAP handler on it  ?

Comment: Thanks  that works fine with me  my issue with this  client  is just i need to use  bindingProvider.getBinding().setHandlerChain